# How to add Genesis Responsive Slider from template instead of widget

Tags: wordpress

I want to add Genesis Responsive Slider from my wordpress page template.How can i do it? just need the name of the function.Please find the link of the plugin
http://wordpress.org/support/plugin/genesis-responsive-slider

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it looks like according to the Genesis slider plugin author it can only be used as a widget. It also supports only a single set of slides so separate slide sets are unsupported.

Sources: wordpress.org/support/topic/shortcode-for-genesis-resposive-slider
wordpress.org/support/topic/multiple-instances-of-slider

I opted to include bxSlider for my WordPress plugin. It's responsive, has touch support and good documentation. http://bxslider.com/